# Mass edit multiple workbooks of the same format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA (as of this morning), so excuse my ignorance. I have a few hundred Excel workbooks, all formatted exactly the same way (just with different text). I'm trying to both format and delete a few sheets within the workbooks (the same for alL).

I recorded a macro that works fine when applied individually, but I'm getting a runtime error when I try to run this as a means of mass format:

```
    Sub LoopFiles()
    Dim MyFileName, MyPath As String
    Dim MyBook As Workbook
    MyPath = "I:\Academic Networks\All scorecard copies, 6.18.2015"
    MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsm")
    Do Until MyFileName = ""
        Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyFileName
        Set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.Run "Workbook1.xlsm!ScorecardMacro"
        MyBook.Save
        MyBook.Close
        MyFileName = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub
```

I keep getting a runtime error (9) - Subscript out of range. Any thoughts?

Here's the formatting/deleting I'm trying to apply to all my workbooks (which works fine when applied to one workbook at a time:

```
Sub ScorecardMacro()
'
' Scorecard Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add
    Sheets("Scorecard").Select
Range("D3:D36").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Sheets("Scorecard").Select
Range("A3:A36").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Sheets("Scorecard").Select
Range("F3:I36").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Checklist").Select
Range("D4:D27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 28
Range("AJ1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Sheets("Checklist").Select
Range("A4:A27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("AJ2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Sheets("Additional Information").Select
Range("A4:B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("BH1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Program Recommendations").Select
Range("A4:D21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("BS1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1,SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A6").Select
    Sheets("Program Recommendations").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Additional Information").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Scorecard").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Checklist").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
```

End Sub

Comment: You really need to be posting the code for `ScorecardMacro` so we can see what safe-guards are missing when it comes to writing generic code to be run on multiple workbooks

Comment: Gotcha. This macro was auto-generated by Excel, so I didn't think anything had to be changed. Thanks for letting me know. Added to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you are trying to access something that doesn't exist.

Since you are deleting something, its better to do all you updates first, then do all the deletes in the end.

If you do some deletes in between and then update, there might be some values/sheets missing

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when I apply my macro individually (just edited my post to include the code), it works fine. It's when I try to loop it on more than one file that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a named range called "filename":
        "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1,SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"

I suspect that name is not defined in the other workbooks.